# Support troubleshooting beginner class code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning coding and believe I followed the test script but I'm getting an error on line 12

tried adjusting spacing but not working.

```
class Song(object):

    def _init_(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print(line)

happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you",
                    "I don't want to get sued",
                    "So I'll stop right there"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around tha family",
                        "With a pocket full of shells"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

It should print out the lyrics to each song but instead I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex40.py", line 12, in <module>
    "So I'll stop right there"])
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

But not sure what I am looking for on line 12

Comment: `__init__` needs **two** underscores on each side...

Comment: thank you! did not see that clearly in the text!

Answer (score 1):

You need *two* underscores on each side of the `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, lyrics):
```

This is because `__init__` has a [special meaning](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) in Python, and by convention all such names start and end with two underscores.

Also, in Python 3, there is no need to inherit from `object`, as [all classes inherit from `object` automatically](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes.html):

```
class Song:
```

There's no harm in keeping the explicit inheritance, though, and it's necessary if you want to support Python 2.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that parameter `object` doesn't have take any parameters, so there's no initialization for it. The parameter for your class should import another class and then initialize it in the `init` function. So just remove object as a parameter. Also add two underscores for `init` function so it looks like `__init__`.